# Ruby on rails database interface

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm used to MySQL but trying to use Ruby on Rails right now. In MySQL, I would have two tables, with one containing a reference to another ("posts" referring to "topic"). A MySQL query doing what I want would be similar to "SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE posts.topic="topic" ("topic" here is a variable).

However, trying to work with the Ruby model stuff has me confused. The variables being passed between the controller and view are null because they are empty tables.

In my controller:

```
def topic
  @topic = Topic.where(params[:topic])
  @posts = Post.where(topic: @topic.object_id)
end
```

I don't know how to select the posts which have the topic defined by the "topic" variable.

In the view:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <p><%= post.title %></p>
<% end %>
```

The migration files:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :text
      t.references :topic
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
class CreateTopics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :topics do |t|
      t.string :topic
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Post and Topic are related, according to your migrations at least, in the models you should be stating"

```
class Topic
  has_many :posts
```

and

```
class Post
  belongs_to :topic
```

Given that you then have an instance of Topic, @topic, you can retrieve all the related records with:

```
@posts = @topic.posts
```

Answer (score 0):

I think those methods you put in your controller are fine where they are, but keep in mind that the Rails way is "fat models, skinny controllers." If you put that logic in the model as a method, it's much easier to read in the controller. Also, you should look into [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes), as they'll help you with queries like this down the line too.

In any case, you should stick the following in your Topic model:

```
scope :by_name, ->(name) { where(topic: name) }
```

That's essentially the same as doing the following:

```
def self.by_name(name)
  where(topic: name)
end
```

On your posts model, you'd be able to do the following:

```
scope :by_topic, ->(topic) { where(topic_id: topic) }
```

The other problem with what you've stuck in your controller is that when you use scopes, or a "where", it returns an array that contains all of the different records that match your query terms. So, when you call @topic = Topic.where(params[:topic]), you're getting back an array of objects. Therefore, when you do a @topic.id, you're trying to get back the id of an array instead of one object.

Based off of what I showed you before, it makes much more sense for you to do this:

```
def topic
  @topic = Topic.by_name(params[:topic]).first #this returns the first record
  @post = Post.by_topic(@topic.id)
end
```

That will return an array of posts that match the first topic name that you query for.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, first a [primer](https://quickleft.com/blog/introduction-to-database-design-on-rails-part-ii/) on how database design and how Rails (really, ActiveRecord) works. Basically, you should be connecting `posts.topic_id = topic.id`, not `posts.topic = topic.topic`.

Your migration is correct as is, `create_table` automatically includes an :id PRIMARY KEY column. That said you should know that these are all equivalent:

```
t.references :topic
t.belongs_to :topic
t.integer :topic_id
```

In your view, instead of embedding `topic.topic` and passing that to the controller when the form is submitted, embed `topic.id` (the [documentation for the select helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) has a good example of this) and in your controller:

```
@topic = Topic.find params[:id]
@posts = @topic.posts
```